# The info from my MYSQL are not showing?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a social network and are adding a notification bar on the site, but the code is not loading the data from the database.

```
$newpm_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pm` 
                          WHERE `to` = '". $_SESSION['id'] ."' 
                          ORDER BY `id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($newpm_sql) == 0) { 
    $newpm = '<div id="notificationTitle">Meddelande</div>
    <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">
       Du har inga meddelanden! 
    </div>
'; 
} else {

    while ( $newpm = mysql_fetch_array( $newpm_sql )) {

        $from_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` 
                                 WHERE `id` = '". $newpm['from'] ."'") 
               or die(mysql_error());
        $from = mysql_fetch_array($from_sql);

        if ($newpm['status'] == 0) { 
            $newpm = '<div id="notificationTitle">Meddelande</div>
                      <div id="notificationsBody" notifications">'. 
                         $newpm['subject'] .' '. $newpm['from'] .
                       '</div>'; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Does anything show up? Errors? White screen? Is there actually data that should be showing up? Have you checked that the SQL is generated properly?

Comment: You're using an API from the last millennium (well, nearly). Come join the 21st century.

Comment: use an error message at else part ,and use an echo comand to display $newpm_sql ,,tell us what is the result

Comment: At least here should be some `echo`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variable `$newpm` for almost everything and therefore destroying what was held in it up to that point.

Use a new variable in the second query, I have used `$row` as an example below

```
$newpm_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pm` 
                          WHERE `to` = '". $_SESSION['id'] ."' 
                          ORDER BY `id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($newpm_sql) == 0) { 
    $newpm = '<div id="notificationTitle">Meddelande</div>
    <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">Du har inga</div>'; 
} else {
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $newpm_sql )) {

        $from_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` 
                                 WHERE `id` = '". $newpm_sql['from'] ."'") 
               or die(mysql_error());
        $from = mysql_fetch_array($from_sql);

        if ($row['status'] == 0) { 
            $newpm = '<div id="notificationTitle">Meddelande</div>
                      <div id="notificationsBody" notifications">'. 
                         $row['subject'] .' '. $row['from'] .
                       '</div>'; 
        }
    }
}
```

> Also you should not be using the `mysql_` database access extension, it is deprecated i.e. soon to be removed. As you are obviously learning, spend your time learning the `mysqli_` extension or the `PDO` extension. See this for some help deciding which you prefer [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Ok, thank you, how do i do so it show the 5 latest insted of only one.

My new problem is that when the user have read there message and this should show instead. but are not.

if (mysql_num_rows($newpm_sql) == 0) { 
    $newpm = '<div id="notificationTitle">Message</div>
    <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">You got no message</div>';

Comment: Sorry that sounds like a new question. Ask another question

Comment: @RiggsFolly OP reposted Smokey http://stackoverflow.com/q/32182247/ - syntax error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Got it and posted an answer fixing the error I missed last time