# The data from my mysql database are not showing correctly

Tags: php, mysql, notifications

How do i do so it show all messages insted of only one, and other problem is that when the user have read there message and this part of the code right below are not showing. The full code can you find at the bottom of the page.

**THIS CODE PART ARE NOT SHOWING AFTER A USER HAVE READ THERE NEW MESSAGE, BUT I WILL NOT SHOW:**

```
    $newpm = '<div id="notificationTitle">Message</div>
    <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">You have no new messages</div>';
```

**THE FULL CODE:**

```
    $newpm_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pm` 
                              WHERE `to` = '". $_SESSION['id'] ."' 
                              ORDER BY `id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($newpm_sql) == 0) { 
        $newpm = '<div id="notificationTitle">Message</div>
        <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">You have no new messages</div>'; 
    } else {
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $newpm_sql )) {

            $from_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` 
                                     WHERE `id` = '". $newpm_sql['from'] ."'") 
                   or die(mysql_error());
            $from = mysql_fetch_array($from_sql);

            if ($row['status'] == 0) { 
                $newpm = '<div id="notificationTitle">Message</div>
                          <div id="notificationsBody" notifications">
<b><a href="page.php?name=profile&id='. $row['from'] .'">'. $row['subject'] .'</a></b><br> '. $row['text'] .'
                           '</div>'; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: *"The full code can you find at the bottom of the page."* - did you start the session? `session_start();` isn't mentioned/shown.

Comment: you also seem to have a syntax error. Look at Stack's syntax highlighting. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: the problem here is that you have an extra quote in `.'  '</div>';` and error reporting would have told you that. Syntax errors are off-topic, as per Stack's standards.

Comment: you also (re)posted this http://stackoverflow.com/q/32158253/ with an upvoted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32158400/ - so what's different with this question?

Comment: Seems like we're blowing bubble here *Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *Yessir, we sure are Ralph.* @Fred-ii-

Comment: I hope the OP will bring us all back a coffee and danish when they get back. *What say you Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *I could eat, Ralph.* @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Me too Sam* @JayBlanchard I'm famished!

Answer (score 0):

First run this:

```
SELECT * FROM `pm` WHERE `to` = '<your SESSION ID>'
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

and see if that returns something.

You can also do:

```
var_dump(mysql_num_rows($newpm_sql));die;
```

after running this mysql_query in first line and see if it returns something you expect.

And also, you can switch to PDO - you will not regret it, as you're now using old php functions.

Answer (score 0):

I see the error I missed last time.

This statement

```
$newpm = '<div id="notificationTitle">Message</div>
<div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">You have no new messages</div>';
```

is being run inside a `while` loop and therefore you should be concatenating these multiple iterations onto `$newpm` using `.=` and not just an `=`

```
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $newpm_sql )) {

        $from_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` 
                                 WHERE `id` = '". $newpm_sql['from'] ."'") 
               or die(mysql_error());
        $from = mysql_fetch_array($from_sql);

        if ($row['status'] == 0) { 


            //$newpm = '<div id="notificationTitle">Message</div>
            newpm .= '<div id="notificationTitle">Message</div>      
                      <div id="notificationsBody" notifications">
                         <b>
                            <a href="page.php?name=profile&id='. $row['from'] .'">'. $row['subject'] .'</a>
                        </b>
                        <br> '. 
                        $row['text'] .'
                      '</div>'; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You definitely deserve a coffee and danish, *with extra toppings.*